# Next.js's API route does not send response

Tags: node.js, next.js

Next.js sends this error when requesting my API route:

```
API resolved without sending a response for /api/login, this may result in stalled requests.
```

The content of the API route is, I guess, valid. Most edgecases was solved. I'll also add that the error was occuring when successfully logged.

```
 export default withSession(async (req, res) => {
    if (req.method !== "POST") {
        return res.status(405).send({ error: "Tylko metoda POST jest dozwolona." });
    }

    const { username, password } = req.body;

    if (!username || !password) {
        return res.status(401).send({ error: "Nazwa użytkownika i hasło nie mogą być puste." });
    }

    try {
        const knex = getKnex();
        const user = await knex<User>("users").select("*").where("username", username).first();

        if (!user) {
            return res.status(401).send({ error: "Użytkownik o takiej nazwie nie istnieje." });
        }

        bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, async function (error) {
            if (error) {
                return res.status(403).send({ error: "Podane hasło jest nieprawidłowe." });
            }

            const { password, ...result } = user;
            req.session.set("user", result);

            await req.session.save();
            res.status(200).send({ message: "Zostałeś zalogowany." });
        });
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(error?.status || 500).send({ error: error.message });
        console.error(error.stack);
    }
});
```

The `withSession` function is a utility for handling `next-iron-session`.

Comment: That's most likely caused by the `bcrypt.compare` callback. Try promisifying the callback and wait for it to resolve.

Answer (score 1):

Attempt to add a `return` before calling the `bcrypt` and on its final response, such as:

```
        return bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, async function (error) {
            if (error) {
                return res.status(403).send({ error: "Podane hasło jest nieprawidłowe." });
            }

            const { password, ...result } = user;
            req.session.set("user", result);

            await req.session.save();
            return res.status(200).send({ message: "Zostałeś zalogowany." });
        });
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it still resolves a no response, somehow. What's strange is that when I test the endpoint with REST client it does returns the valid response, status 200 with message. The fetch operation also works fine, but the Next.js is still showing a no response error in the console.

Comment: maybe something w/ the build? or caching?

Answer (score 0):

You can delete this warning by exporting a **config** object to change the default configs.

it tells the server that this route is being handled by an external resolver

```
export const config = {
  api: {
    externalResolver: true,
  },
}
```

[reference](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/api-middlewares)